# Ubuntu 15.10 then windows 7 dual boot issue

Tags: grub2, windows, 15.10, grub-efi

I've been using Ubuntu 15.10 for a while, but recently installed Windows 7 (quite reluctantly) on the same SSD (converting partition table to GPT as required) but on separate NTFS partition.
I thought I did reinstall grub properly, but the current behaviour of my PC tells me otherwise: it was able to boot Windows ok (thru boot override) but not Ubunutu.

I then proceeded to use boot-repair-cd from a bootable flash drive, which went fine until the kernel-purge-then-reinstall step (gets stuck at "(ins)").
I now cannot boot either OS, either EFI or legacy.

Whoever's kind enough to look into my problem can find further details at http://paste.ubuntu.com/16207880/
Per these details, there seems to be some grub installed on sdc (my system disk), but not in a bootable way.
sda and sdb are RAID mounted in my case and only contain data.

I'm at a road block here, gray hair growing by the minute!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk has no boot loaders. My *educated guess* about what happened, based on your description, is:

1. You installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.
2. When you tried to install Windows 7, you booted in EFI/UEFI mode, so it complained about the MBR partition table and you converted it to GPT and installed Windows in EFI/UEFI mode. This would have rendered Windows bootable and Ubuntu unbootable. This could have been repaired, but....
3. You booted Boot Repair in BIOS mode, and proceeded to trash the [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) that held the Windows boot loader, thus rendering Windows unbootable; and for whatever reason, Boot Repair was unable to get Linux booting again.

At this point, I recommend you [read my page on the CSM and its perils](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for background information. Without an understanding of the CSM, you're likely to dig yourself into the same hole again.

It's almost always best to install both OSes in a dual-boot in the same boot mode -- that is, both in BIOS mode or both in EFI mode. Mixing boot modes is a recipe for disaster. Furthermore, given the way most EFIs are designed, it's usually best if that boot mode be EFI; as my page describes, using BIOS mode turns the boot process into a complicated mess that's as likely to lead to problems as to a successful boot. Thus, I have some specific suggestions:

- **Disable your CSM.** This is the single most important thing to do.
- Change the type code of `/dev/sdc1` so that it's an ESP. (It's currently marked as a BIOS Boot Partition, which is useless for EFI-mode booting.) Note that there's a chance that this partition still holds the Windows boot loader, so correctly marking it as an ESP might be all you need to do to get Windows booting; but you may need to create a new FAT32 filesystem on it and do more repairs. You can change the type code using `gdisk` by changing it from EF02 to EF00; or with `parted` or GParted by removing the `bios_grub` flag and replacing it with a `boot` flag.
- Re-install the Windows boot loader using Windows tools. You should ask for details of how to do this on a Windows forum.
- Install an EFI boot loader for Linux. There are a couple of relatively simple ways to do this:

  - Use Boot Repair, but boot the repair disk *in EFI mode*. (If you can't boot in EFI mode, the disk is probably prepared incorrectly. My page on the CSM that I referenced earlier goes into this subject in detail.)
  - Prepare a USB flash drive or CD-R image of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) (Images for both are on that page.) Boot with it, and using rEFInd, boot Ubuntu. You can then install rEFInd to the hard disk using the Debian package or PPA.

Instead of those last two top-level bullet points, you could re-install one or both OSes -- but be sure to do so using the same boot mode (preferably EFI mode). Note that this will go best if you disable the CSM and fix the type code of your ESP.

Answer (score 0):

You're bang on with what happened.
Discussing with other people, I'm realizing that dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 on a single SSD with a GPT partition table is not a diserable route to go down.
Aparently MBR/legacy setup is the least problematic. I reinstalled everything that way, works now like a charm.
Thanks for your time.