# Can't boot Windows 7 dual-boot installed after installing Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

**Previous issues:**

My laptop has had a rough year. It is an Asus F555L and originally had windows 8.1 in it. Two months ago it had the infamous [100% disk usage](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-keeps-slows-down-to-100-disk-usage-and/cd787f8d-e7b4-4872-aecb-6f0cd15ad942?auth=1) issue which I could not solve after a week of looking in every forum. Anyway, I finally formatted the hard drive and installed ubuntu 14.04 alone on it, which rather surprisingly has been working flawlessly since then.

**Goal:**

However I would like to have the option two dual boot to windows (mainly for gaming).

**What I did:**

From an ubuntu live usb first I made an 120GB NFTS partition on my drive with gparted. I then changed the partition table from MBR to GPT with fdisk following [this tutorial](http://www.firewing1.com/blog/2012/03/05/how-convert-gpt-disk-layout-ms-dosmbr-layout-without-data-loss-and-gigabyte-hybrid), apparently succesfully. I have burned an windows 7 iso in a usb and after enabling "launch csm" option in the bios and making sure it was on a 2.0 USB port (...I have suffered to find out all this...) managed to boot from it.

**The problem:**

I installed windows 7 on the NFTS partiton, however I am unable to boot it, and the option to boot windows doesn't appear on the bios.

I tried to install again windows7 and erased everything in the partition several times.

I tried to repair windows with the windows7 iso (bootrec /FixMbr /FixBooT /RebuildBcr).

I also tried to install boot-repair on ubuntu.

In particular when I do /RebuildBcd it says that 0 windows installations have been found, but when previously asked which windows installation I wanted to fix it was there. Also the files are there. Moreover when I boot Ubuntu (which I still works and has all my files, surprising after all this messing around) and open gparted, the NFTS partition has the boot label.

**The actual question:**

Any ideas on how to fix the windows 7 installation?

I have everything backed up and the next thing I was going to try was to format all the hard drive and install windows 7 from scratch, but I would prefer to avoid having to set up ubuntu again. 
Btw I also have a windows 8.1 iso but I prefer windows 7.

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/767077/ubuntu-15-10-then-windows-7-dual-boot-issue, which I believe describes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I formated the whole disk and installed first windows and the ubuntu (I did the partitions from the windows installation disk). It now works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the windows startup on the grub list, you can use the Ubuntu live Cd and install the grub-repair `sudo apt-get install grub-repair` grub repair will autoscan for Windows partitions and will add a entry on de grub so startup list